# Problem with postgreSQL version after an update

Tags: linux, postgresql, linux-mint

I'm working with Linux Mint 19.1. I update postgresql from verion 10.10 to version 11.

I know that psql is the command line interface and its version can be independent of the Postgres server. So, if I do:

```
$psql --version
```

I get:

```
psql (PostgreSQL) 11.5 (Ubuntu 11.5-3.pgdg18.04+1)
```

but when I do

```
select version();
```

I get:

```
PostgreSQL 10.10 (Ubuntu 10.10-1.pgdg18.04+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled
by gcc (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 7.4.0, 64-bit
```

How can I update the version of the server ?

Comment: Did you really do an update or have you just installed another version? I guess your version 11 runs on a different port (if it is running at all).

Comment: Perhaps server and cli are in different packages ? Either case your question is off topic